# How to split the array value in variable in php?

Tags: php, ajax

I used serialize() to get the form values in ajax call.Now i get an array value ..I want the array to be stored in variable..

Here is what i'm getting:

```
Array ( [datewise] => 05/22/2015 [mealplan] => AP )
```

I want like this:

```
$date=05/22/2015;
$meal=AP;
```

How to store like this from an array?

Comment: [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: `$date=$array['datewise'];$meal=$array['mealplan'];`

Comment: @Ghost wont work the key names are not the exact desired variable names

Comment: @Dagon thats just variable names, plus less typing :p

Comment: i like typing I get paid per key press !HJRFTYBDFTY DVRJVFGYMFVRDNHFBYJGMUBGKGMHKUGNKMUKI

Comment: @Dagon you're probably richer than bill gates right now :D

Comment: and extract is dangerous - source of ajax may not be safe

Comment: hey any idea how to split it up...

Comment: hey - we gave you 2 options above

Comment: i  need to get extracted since with that value i need to fetch the data from the database

Comment: $date=$array['datewise'];$meal=$array['mealplan']; its not working out...an undefined variable array message s shown up

Comment: is the above array named `$array` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$var = Array ( [datewise] => 05/22/2015 [mealplan] => AP );

extract($var);
```

Now you can use the `$datewise` and `$mealplan` variables.

Comment: better hope that incoming ajax data is 'safe'

Comment: But even in your case "$date=$array['datewise'];" could be some malicious SQL inject ;-) if he stores that in the database or does some query with it ...

Comment: I wouldn't ever recommend using extract, even the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) suggests not to.

Comment: it's only used for  selecting data from database purpose....So is it safe to use this function...

Comment: yes you can use, column name will become the individual variables

Answer (score 0):

```
$expected_keys = array('datewise', 'mealplan');

foreach ($expected_keys as $key) {
    ${$key} = $your_array[$key];
}
```

But even with that, I still don't see a reason to do this at all. If the data is already in the array, and hopefully validated, then why not use the array as-is?

Comment: as dangerous as extract.

Comment: Fair enough, although the question did not refer to sanitizing input, so a bit out of context. I'll edit for a "safer" approach.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, this is very dangerous. You are allowing artibrary injection of variables into your script.

Why don't you use the array directly?

Or just re-assign if you must.

$datewise = $array['datewise'];

Having the explicit assignments is a good thing! It's called readable code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
    'datewise' => '05/22/2015',
    'mealplan' => 'AP',
];

list($date, $meal) = array_values($array);
```

Debugging:

```
var_dump($date);
var_dump($meal);
```

yields

```
string(10) "05/22/2015"
string(2) "AP"
```